# EF Core Set Identity Insert On and SaveChanges

Tags: ef-core-2.1

We create a sample database, but in the creation we set our identities to specific values. To turn on Identity Insert we use

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand ( "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tool ON;" );
```

we then call

```
context.SaveChanges ();
```

and then execute another sql command to turn Identity Insert off.

When we Add the entity is there a way to insert Identity Insert ON SQL command as text before the ADD and then to insert Identity Insert OFF SQL command as text after the Add.

I picture `SaveChanges` as generating the SQL text that will do the insert, this is why I am wondering if there is a way to insert SQL commands.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?